# MS Access linked tables automatically long integers

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, linked-tables

I have a large amount of linked tables in my access database that are going to be refreshed regularly and manipulated via queries. However, access is automatically determining some important fields as long integers because the beginning values of the field are usually 0s. When the value is not 0, it is goes up to 4 decimal places. Since I have so many tables and since they will be replaced each week with a new table of the same name (thus the link), it is not feasible to manually change the formatting of the fields to double within the excel document itself. Is there any way to override this so that any linked table with a field that is "number" is automatically a double?

Edit:
Basically I will be running reports that are going to be exported to excel documents each week. I have set up an "active" folder that has the current excel files I need to import. Each week the excel files in the active folder will be deleted and replaced with files of the same name and format, but with new data. This is why I am using linked tables to those files.

Linked table example:

```
revised_full_cost   change
615.194               0
402.402               0
1548.193            -4464
5329.836              0
```

Versus the actual excel file:

```
revised_full_cost   change
615.194               0
402.402               0
1548.193          -4464.207
5329.836              0
```

As you can see the "change" field is being determined as an integer by the linked table and rounding when I need the decimals

Comment: When you link tables, you don't change the data types, unless I am misunderstanding something. Can you explain the setup/process you're trying to accomplish to get to this point?

Comment: I added some more information to the edit section to help clarify. I need the fields that are formatted in excel as "general" and being picked up in the linked access tables as "number, long integers" to be picked up as "double", but without manually doing so

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out (and I feel dumb):

When linking tables you can choose the desired format for each field when going through the linked table wizard steps.